# javascript responsive menu needs to be refreshed whenever media query point requests change

Tags: javascript

wonder if anyone can advise.

I am very new to web design and am trying to use a javascript responsive menu code detailed in Tim Kadlec's great Responsive Design book.  The menu works fine as mobile menu and then changes to full screen upon my media query, but if I move the browser window I then need to "refresh" every time to make the menu state change to what it should be.  Could anyone advise me what I am dong wrong?!  Many thanks, Webstudent :

```
window.onload = function() {
    var nav = document.getElementById('nav'); 
    var navItem = nav.getElementsByTagName('li');
    //is it floated?
    var floated = navItem[0].currentStyle ? el.currentStyle['float'] : document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(navItem[0],null).getPropertyValue('float');

    if (floated != 'left') {
        var collapse = document.getElementById('nav-collapse');

        //toggle class utility function
        var classToggle = function( element, tclass ) {
            var classes = element.className,
            pattern = new RegExp( tclass );
            hasClass = pattern.test( classes );
            //toggle the class
            classes = hasClass ? classes.replace( pattern, '' ) : classes + ' ' + tclass;
            element.className = classes.trim();
        };

        classToggle(nav, 'hide');
        classToggle(collapse, 'active');
        collapse.onclick = function() {
            classToggle(nav, 'hide');
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe include a Jfiddle in your question!

Comment: Thanks for the guidance qLuke, I had not come across Jfiddle.  My code is at https://jsfiddle.net/webdesignstudent/p5qe8d5v/